# Переход на другой UIViewController до начала обработки данных

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Добрый вечер!
Начинаю осваиваться в Objective-C и пишу на нём свое первое приложение.

При переходе с одного `ViewController` на другой, передаю через `segue` параметры, которые в методе второго контроллера обрабатываются в `viewDidLoad` и там же забираются данные с сервера.

Так вот как сделать так, чтобы сначала визуально осуществлялся переход на второй контроллер, а уж потом начинали грузиться данные? (видимо, придется добавить вьюху с `ActivityIndicator` поверх всех остальных и делать её `visible` вначале загрузки данных и `hidden` после окончания).

Сейчас это выглядит так - нажал на кнопку, она стала `selected`... жду загрузку... переходит на второй контроллер с уже заполненными данными... не по фэн-шую как-то.

Буду признателен любым подсказкам.

Спасибо!

**добавлено:**

Так же почитал, что в случае использования TableViewController, не получится натянуть на него ActivityIndicator. Поэтому, подойдет и такой вариант: 1.нажал на кнопку 2.увидел индикатор загрузки 3.(данные загрузились) 4.скрыл индикатор 5.перешел на другой контроллер.

Вот только как отловить события на первом контроллере, когда данные начали обрабатываться во втором и непосредственно перед переходом на второй контроллер, когда данные загружены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо начинать грузить данные в методе `viewDidAppear` второго контроллера. Или грузить во `viewDidLoad`, но в фоновом потоке, чтобы не морозить главный поток, в котором работает весь UI.

Решение с фоновым потоком зависит от метода получения данных.

Comment: спасибо! ушел читать про жизненные циклы контроллеров.

Comment: А знаете как вывести поверх TableViewController индикатор загрузки?
Нашел советы, что надо мол переписать под обычный ViewController с вложенными TableView и View с индикатором... не хочется переделывать... может есть способ?

Comment: Если дизайн таков, что контента еще в таблице нет, можно  в ней показать одну большую ячейку во весь экран с индикатором по середине. Но вообще можно и так сделать - посмотрите MBProgressHUD. Чтобы с TableViewController не было проблем, нужно чтобы в момент показа сложенного в его view индикатора не происходил скролл или изменения его размеров...